# Need download link for gitlab package for Redhat CentOS 7

Tags: download, package, gitlab

The server on which i wish to install gitlab is unable to download the gitlab package as shown below.

```
# curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.rpm.sh
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: packages.gitlab.com; Unknown error
```

Can you please help with some solution and especially an alternate link where i can download the package from web browser.

I will then upload the installer to my server and then install it in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

The GitLab Documentation has [instructions on manual install](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/manual_install.html), which includes a where to download.

For the Community edition, you can find the list of packages here: https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce